# "Encountered error while generating package metadata" ... "error in demjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid."

Tags: python

I've been trying to install some packages in my program using the `pip install -r requirement.txt` format but all I get is:

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in demjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

What can I do to get rid of that error?

Comment: What packages are you are trying to install? As the message indicates, it's an issue with the specific packages.

Comment: appdirs==1.4.3
attrs==19.1.0
black==19.3b0
Click==7.0
cycler==0.10.0
demjson==2.2.4
kiwisolver==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.1.1
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.17.0
opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
pandas==0.25.1
Pillow==6.2.0
pyparsing==2.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.2
six==1.12.0
toml==0.10.0
virtualenv==16.7.4
xlrd==1.2.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
yagmail==0.11.220
yapf==0.28.0

Comment: Those are the packages  i'm trying to install

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but I googled the error message and found this issue on GitHub: [Setuptools 58.0.0 has removed support for 2to3 during builds, breaks demjson for Python 3.x](https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson/issues/40)